# Does the latest SP 2013 security update contains all the previous ones like CUs?

Tags: security, patching

I need to apply security updates to my production server to match my dev server. I am seeing a list of Sharepoint securiy updates installed on the DEV . Do i need to install all of them to Prod in that sequence or just install the latest one ( assuming the one with the latest KB number is the latest one )  and that will take care of the previous ones ? I think Cumulative Updates work that way but not sure of Security Updates .

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. They may contain partial or even full fixes for previous security issues as they use newer binaries, but unless the TechNet article states that it replaces a previous security fix, you must apply all security fixes from your previous patch level (e.g. SP1) to be up-to-date.